# jquery disable form submit on enter mvc 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

i try do disable enter in my form using jquery, but didnt work...

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Contrato", FormMethod.Post, new { id="formContrato"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
.
.
.

}
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $('#formContrato').keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == '13') {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$('#formContrato').submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Also don't forget to wrap this code in a `$(document).ready` if you are executing it before the actual form such as for example in the `<head>` section of your HTML. If you place the script at the end it is not necessary.

Comment: I need it in only this form. Dont work in same with your answer

Comment: `$('#formContrato')` applies only to the form with specified id. It won't apply to all forms. What doesn't work?

Comment: right right. I was find solution:
script:

`function removerEnter(e){
        if (e.which == 13) {
            e.target.nextSibling.nextSibling.focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
}`

In input's:

`<input type="text" onkeypress="removerEnter(event)"/>`